# can we scan structure members through structure pointers?

Tags: c

i have tried the below written code but it did not work. may i know why? is it possible to scan structure members through structure pointers ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
struct book
{
  int isdn;
  float price;
 };
 struct book b,*ptr;
 void main()
 {
   clrscr();
   b.isdn=10;
   b.price=150.75;
   printf("\n%d %f",b.isdn,b.price);
   ptr=&b;
   printf("\n%d %f",ptr->isdn,ptr->price);
   scanf("%d %f",&ptr->isdn,&ptr->price); //this statement do not work,why?
   printf("\n%d %f",ptr->isdn,ptr->price);
   getch();
 }
```

Comment: It does work, there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Are you seriously asking why scanf doesn't work? [whathaveyoutried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: What's the problem? It should work. However, `void main()` should be `int main()`.

Comment: By the way, why do you need the pointer? Isn't `&b.price` good enough?

Answer (score 0):

That code does work, and scanf does work that way. I'll refer you to read some

Did you read the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) on how `scanf()` works?

You need to pass in the data exactly as the format string specifies. So in your case:

```
scanf("%d %f",&ptr->isdn,&ptr->price);
```

You need to pass in an integer, a space, and a float, for example:

> 5 2.3

Then `ptr->isdn` will have 5 and `ptr->price` will have 2.3. If that's not happening for you then perhaps this isn't all your code, or maybe you miss copied something?